# How to render an image with html2canvas in several z-index layers correctly?

Tags: javascript, image, z-index, html2canvas

I have an element "article" that contains a "div" which at same time has 4 "img" in different "z-index" from 1 to 4, overlayed in a clip effect, so I am trying to capture this parent element "article" with html2canvas. It captures the last img from last layer z-index 4 but not the other img, is it a problem of css style, a not implemented function of html2canvas or what?

How do I solve this problem?

This is for a django project.

style.css

```css
article{
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
    top:0px;
    width:841px;
    height:752px;
    background:#999;
    float: right;
}
/* Estilos para visor en cuadrantes */
#img1 {
    width:841px;
    height:752px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#img2 {
    width:841px;
    height:752px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    z-index: 2;
}
#img3 {
    width:841px;
    height:752px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    z-index: 3;
}
#img4 {
    width:841px;
    height:752px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display: none;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

script.js

```
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function(){
    getScreen();
})

function getScreen(){
    var texto="Captura";
    html2canvas([document.getElementById("articulo").innerHTML],{
        allowTaint: true,
        logging: true,
        dpi: 192,
        onrendered: function(canvas){
            $("#blank").attr('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
            $("#blank").attr('download', texto + '.png');
            $("#blank")[0].click();
            //document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        }
    });
}
```

index.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="save">(g)uardar captura</button>
            <div id="caption">
                <span id="caption-text"></span>
            </div>
            <a href="" id="blank"></a>
        </aside>
            <article id="articulo">
            <div id="contenedor">
                <img src="" id="img1">
                <img src="" id="img2">
                <img src="" id="img3">
                <img src="" id="img4">
            </div>
            </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Expected:    "Capture.png" containing 4 images with clip effect
[image]

Actual:     only img 4

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had to add `position:"relative"` to every element at the same level as my images. So perhaps add the `position:"relative"` style to all of your images.[image: This image illustrates the before and after of Position relative.]